# Ambigous project name nuget : appveyor

Tags: c#, nuget, appveyor

I have a nuget package that I build on my master branch or for releasing a version.

The problem is that, only in appveyor I have :

```
Restoring packages for C:\projects\askmethat-xforms-controls\src\Askmethat.XForms.Controls.NuGet\Askmethat.XForms.Controls.NuGet.nuproj...
nuget : Ambiguous project name 'Askmethat.XForms.Controls'.
At line:1 char:1
+ nuget restore .\src\Askmethat.XForms.Controls.sln
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Ambiguous proje...orms.Controls'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Command executed with exception: Ambiguous project name 'Askmethat.XForms.Controls'.
```

This error happens when I try to restore the nuget package for the nuget project.

Here the last build :

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/AlexTeixeira/askmethat-xforms-controls/build/1.1.1-CI-11-bfnthmbj

Here the project in Github:

https://github.com/AlexTeixeira/Askmethat-XForms-Controls/tree/master/src

I think the error comes from the project Forms ( a netstandar library ).

If i had a package ID to this project the restore not failed, but my nuget package have a dependencie to this package id...

Of course, all works perfecly on my machine : macOs up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple projects within your solution, share the same assembly name `Askmethat.XForms.Controls`. Could you perhaps try making them unique? [Here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5621) is the issue tracked in NuGet.

Comment: Yeap, I changes the assembly for the .Net standard Library and after some changes my plugin work as expected...